# Sql Server JDBC Connection Reset Error : Only on Amazon EC2

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jakarta-ee, jboss, amazon-ec2

**Context: The Cloud**

We have a java-based web application that we normally host on our own servers. Recently we used Amazon Web Services (AWS EC2) cloud to host an instance.

This "cloud setup" matches our typical "on site" setup: one server for the app server, another server for the database server. (Several app servers point to the same database server)

**The problem**
In this cloud setup, we receive intermittent "connection reset by peer errors" between the database and the jdbc driver, where at (seemingly) random intervals and at random points in the codebase, the database connection fails.

Here are a few error excerpts for the log

**Stack Trace Example 1:**

```
at com.participate.pe.genericdisplay.client.taglib.GenDisplayViewTag.doStartTag(GenDisplayViewTag.java:77)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:170)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:304)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getMetaData(SQLServerConnection.java:1734)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection.getMetaData(WrappedConnection.java:354)
```

**Stack Trace Example 2**

```
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1368)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1355)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(IOBuffer.java:1532)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:3274)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:4437)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:4389)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$1ConnectionCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:1457)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:4026)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1416)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectionCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1462)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.setAutoCommit(SQLServerConnection.java:1610)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.checkTransaction(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:429)
```

**Technical Environment**

- Jboss 4.2.2.GA (Jboss-Web 2.0/ Tomcat 6)
- MSSQL 2005 2.0 jdbc driver

**Some points**

- We have *never* seen this problem in
  our own environment (i.e. own data centers) running the application for several years
- This led me to conclude "something funny is going on with Amazon network environment". I may be wrong/missing something/etc.
- This problem only occurs with our application. We have other java and php applications which have not had this problem. The other java application uses a different jdbc driver (jtds, afaik)
- It doesn't seem like a simple connection timeout

**Questions**

-Has anyone seen this before?
-If it's an EC2 "known issue", can we configure our way around the problem (i.e. make sure everything is on its own subnet or virtual private cloud (vpc) ?
-Any jdbc driver settings to get past this problem?

** Update **
I've extended and increased the bounty on this question.

On  extra bit of information: the two virtual servers (database and application server) were on different subnets--i.e. one hop between the two servers.

In a non-cloud environment we have "zero hops" bewtewn the two servers.

Our hosting admins said we had no control over the subnets of our EC2 instances. This made me wonder if virtual private cloud would help.

thanks in advance

will

Comment: Did you try to switch the JDBC driver to jTDS? Should be an easy try.

Comment: A driver change would require a full qa cycle.  In theory, all jdbc drivers work the same (i.e. "In theory communism works. ")...In practice, they have slight variations....so it's not an option for us at this point.

Comment: Are you sharing connections across several threads in your application? Or is there a network element like a firewall that is dropping connections after a preset amount of time (I'm afraid I'm not knowledgeable about EC2)? The second stack trace, is the result of an IOException being encountered when reading from the channel. The exception itself was not handled correctly, because the underlying logical connection (the SQLServerConnection instance) itself was closed earlier. This would suggest that either the logical connection was shared, or that the underlying physical link was disrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a word of caution on usind DBCP/connection pool features to mitigate the issue - the more you enable 'testOnBorrow' and other features, the more you can introduce latency or other performance changing affects on the system.  I don't know if DBCP still does this or not, but a few years ago it would generate actual test queries to test the connection - full stack, database responses - not just at the network layer.  The above link from Brian brings back horrific memories from the early 2000s on surrounding re-try logic for JDBC connection management.

Anyway, it's tough to really root cause this, other than gather evidence and eliminate the 'seemingly random' to a specific set of conditions:

- You could try to throw up a Wireshark/PCAP trace, find when it happens, and send the results to both Amazon and Microsoft to see if they can root cause it
- You could try the above with certain test harnesses to isolate the problem (JMeter tests to get concurrency up), bounce the network connection, watch for recovery, etc
- You could try alternative versions of SQL Server to discount a SQL Server/JDBC driver bug that has since been fixed.
- If DNS is used in connection strings, could use IP addresses to validate nslookup issues

I'm not a SQL Server expert, but another route for research could be within the related products domain - e.g. see if anyone experienced similar issues with TFS/Sharepoint (e.g. such as http://nickhoggard.wordpress.com/2009/12/07/further-experiences-with-tfs-2010-beta-2-on-amazon-ec2/ )

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is related or not.  We experienced something similar with an app that we were running in the EC2 environment.  Same symptom, that the database connection would intermittently close.  We were using MSSQL 1.2 driver.  Also, we would see the errors usually after a delay or idle time with the connection.  Our assumption (never proven) was that something in the network layer was closing the connection and the client wasn't detecting it, so it became stale.

We were able to work around it because we were using commons connection pools, and had the pool recreate the connection on failure.  We eventually moved the application out of EC2 and didn't see the issue again.

Comment: Hi, This is the most helpful answer so far--i..e confirming someone has seen a similar problem, but I'm really interested in the "root cause"..so I've extended and increased the bounty

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this issue in both the EC2 environment and the Windows Azure environment. I think connection retry logic needs to be a standard part of your design when working in a distributed computing environment.

[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartr/archive/2010/06/18/sql-azure-connection-retry.aspx) is for SQL Azure - but I think it equally applies to EC2 and all drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I can also confirm that this happens and will spin up a lower priority investigation since it's not production critical.
Our production servers are in our data center.  We use developer laptops to run our applications.  Neither of these get this issue once we configured c3p0 connection pool timeouts and test period (see article:  http://www.codefin.net/2007/05/hibernate-and-mysql-connection-timeouts.html).

However, we do have a development staging server that is in EC2 and it does indeed happen there.  If I find something that seems to work, I'll ping back.  Also, I'm using mysql.  I see that you are using MS SQL Server so it is across database vendors.